# Lookup value in dataframe using multiindex

Tags: pandas

I am looking up a value in a dataframe using a multi-index. df[value1,value2]. This works, but throws a keyerror if the value is not in the index. I can handle the exception but is there an equivalent syntax to a python dict.get()? That is, I would prefer the lookup to return None if the value is not found.

Mark

Comment: Did you actually *try* calling `get`, or reading any of the [documentation on indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)? It's pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `DataFrame.get()`:

```
In [50]: from pandas.util.testing import makeCustomDataframe as mkdf

In [51]: df = mkdf(5, 2, c_idx_nlevels=2, data_gen_f=lambda *args: rand())

In [52]: df
Out[52]:
C0       C_l0_g0  C_l0_g1
C1       C_l1_g0  C_l1_g1
R0
R_l0_g0    0.155    0.989
R_l0_g1    0.427    0.330
R_l0_g2    0.951    0.720
R_l0_g3    0.745    0.485
R_l0_g4    0.674    0.841

In [53]: level = df.columns[0]

In [54]: level
Out[54]: ('C_l0_g0', 'C_l1_g0')

In [55]: df.get(level)
Out[55]:
R0
R_l0_g0    0.155
R_l0_g1    0.427
R_l0_g2    0.951
R_l0_g3    0.745
R_l0_g4    0.674
Name: (C_l0_g0, C_l1_g0), dtype: float64

In [56]: df.get('how are you?')

In [57]: df.get('how are you?', 'Fine')
Out[57]: 'Fine'
```

You can also just define a function:

```
def get_from_index(df, key, default=None):
    try:
        return df.loc[key]
    except KeyError:
        return default
```

Comment: Hi Phillip, I modified your example to index on a single column across rows. df = mkdf(5, 2, r_idx_nlevels=1, data_gen_f=lambda *args: np.random.rand())
print (df.loc['R_l0_g0'])
print(df.get('R_l0_g0', 'Fine')) df.loc[] return the row. df.get() return Fine.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: Phillip, sorry it is a bit cryptic. I indexed on a single column R0. When I want to look a df row using the index I use df.loc['R_10_g0']. I then tried to use df.get('R_10_g0',Fine) which return 'Fine'. The df.get() did not find the row by the value in the index R0. Of course, the df.loc[] throws a keyerror if the index does not match.

Comment: There isn't a way to do what you want using `get`, what's wrong with catching the exception? You can always monkey patch a method onto `DataFrame` as well.

Comment: Thank you Phillip. Catching the exception is fine. I wanted to be sure I did not miss something in the documentation on df.get() silencer's solution is another option: x = df.ix[(df.index.get_level_values('R0') == 'R_l0_g0') & (df.index.get_level_values('R1') == 'xR_l1_g0')] This will return an empty list if the value is not found in the multi-index. -Mark

Comment: Sure. I've added a function that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If your df has a multiindex in columns 'key1' and 'key2' and you want to look up value xxx on key1 and yyy on key2 , try this

```
df.ix[df.index.get_level_values('key1') == xxx & 
df.index.get_level_values('key2') == yyy]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, your example worked when I created a multi-index on two columns named R0 and R1. I had to wrap each selector expression with parens as follows. x = df.ix[(df.index.get_level_values('R0') == 'R_l0_g0') & (df.index.get_level_values('R1') == 'xR_l1_g0')]